# Transfer information from website's database to Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am planning to make a Chrome extension that will collect and display data from my website. The data is stored in a database, and I need to transfer that data to the Chrome extension. What is the most secure way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax to send and receive data to and from your backend.

For more security you can use socket IO to send the data back and forth.
for more details about socketIO visit [socket.io](https://socket.io/)

Make sure you have cors enabled on your backend. If you are using PHP then edit .htaccess file for cors and if you are using Node JS as backend language, Install cors package.